# add assigned ordered number to array entry php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have an assigned array from mysql results and I simply want to number them starting at one. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$out[] = array("ASSIGNED INTEGER", $row['total']);        
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a variable as a counter, to keep track of the line you're on :

```
$counter = 1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $out[] = array($counter, $row['total']);
    $counter++;
}
```

Or, if you want your resulting `$out` array have results indexed from `1`, instead of `0`, you could use something like this to set the index yourself :

```
$counter = 1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $out[$counter] = $row['total'];
    $counter++;
}
```

Or any idea derived from this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $out[] = array($i++, $row['total']);        
}
```

Comment: You should do ++$i or $i = 1 to start the numbering at 1.